# Length of polygon in R

Tags: r, data.table, r-sf

I want to calculate length of each polygon.
-Around each polygon I created points (st_sample),
-from combiantion of points I created all possible polyline,
-for polylines which are inside polygon I calucalted length,
-the longest polyline is my result (max length of poylgon).

[image: My problem of calculating length of polygon]

I wrote code which got me results but it is really slow. Do you have some solution for improvment of my code? I know that with two loops I cannot expect some miracle about speed but I do not know how get results another way.

If nothing else mybe at least some alterntive solution for creating all polyline from combination of points for one polygon in one step without loop ? :)

thank you

```
library(sf)
library(data.table)

poly=st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
poly=poly[1:10,]
poly=st_cast(poly,"POLYGON")
poly$max_length=0

##Combination of 10 points, withot repetiton
aa=CJ(1:10,1:10)
aa=aa[!duplicated(t(apply(aa[,.(V1, V2)], 1, sort))),][V1!=V2]

##for each polygon create sample of coordinates along line, from them I create polyline and calculated length for linestring which are inside polygon

for (ii in 1:nrow(poly)){
  ncl=st_cast(poly[ii,],"LINESTRING")
  ##sample of point along line
  ncp=st_cast(st_sample(ncl,10, type="regular", exact=T),"POINT")
  
  ##create empty sf 
  aaa=st_sf(st_sfc())
  st_crs(aaa)="NAD27"
  
  ##for each combination of points create linestring and calculate length only for polylines which are inside polygon
  for (i in 1:nrow(aa)){
 aaa=rbind(aaa,st_sf(geometry=st_cast(st_union(ncp[t(aa[i])]),"LINESTRING")))
  }
poly$max_length[ii]=as.numeric(max(st_length(aaa[unlist(st_contains(poly[ii,],aaa)),])))
}
```

Second attempt with running function inside data.table. One loop less but problem is probably second loop.

```
poly=st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
poly=poly[1:10,]
poly=st_cast(poly,"POLYGON")
poly$max_length=0

##Combination of 10 points, withot repetiton
aa=CJ(1:10,1:10)
aa=aa[!duplicated(t(apply(aa[,.(V1, V2)], 1, sort))),][V1!=V2]

overFun <- function(x){
  
  ncl=st_cast(x[,geometry],"LINESTRING")
  ##sample of point along line
  ncp=st_cast(st_sample(ncl,40, type="regular", exact=T),"POINT")
  
  ##create empty sf 
  aaa=st_sf(st_sfc())
  st_crs(aaa)="NAD27"
  
  ##for each combination pof points create linestring and calculate length
  for (i in 1:nrow(aa)){
    aaa=rbind(aaa,st_sf(geometry=st_cast(st_union(ncp[t(aa[i])]),"LINESTRING")))
  }
  
  as.numeric(max(st_length(aaa[unlist(st_contains(x[,geometry],aaa)),])))}  

setDT(poly)

##run function inside data.table
poly[,max_length:=overFun(poly), by=seq(nrow(poly))]
```

Edit: I found some solution for my problem which is enough fast for my needs.
Using parallel library inside data.table with function which also work on a data.table. There is still question why some polyline are excluded with function st_contains (see picture upper). Maybe some problem with precision?

```
library(sf)
library(data.table)

poly=st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
poly=st_cast(poly,"POLYGON")
setDT(poly)

##Combination of 10 points, withot repetiton
aa=CJ(1:10,1:10)
aa=aa[!duplicated(t(apply(aa[,.(V1, V2)], 1, sort))),][V1!=V2]

overFun <- function(x){
  
ncl=st_cast(poly[1,geometry],"LINESTRING")
##sample of point along line
ncp=st_cast(st_sample(ncl,10, type="regular", exact=T),"POINT")
  
df=data.table(ncp[aa[,V1]],ncp[aa[,V2]] )
  
df[,v3:=st_cast(st_union(st_as_sf(V1),st_as_sf(V2)),"LINESTRING"), by=seq(nrow(df))]
as.numeric(max(st_length(df[unlist(st_contains(poly[1,geometry], df$v3)),]$v3)))}

library(parallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
clusterExport(cl, list("overFun","data.table","st_cast","CJ","poly","st_sample","st_sf","st_sfc","aa","st_length","st_union",
                       "st_as_sf","st_contains"))
system.time(poly[,c("max_length"):=.(clusterMap(cl, overFun, poly$geometry)),])
stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: what do you mean by "max length of polygons" ?

Comment: I want to calculate length of each polygon. 
-Around each polygon I created points (st_sample), 
-from combiantion of points I created all possible polyline,
-for polylines which are inside polygon  I calucalted length,  
-the longest polyline is my result (max length of poylgon).

Sorry for my english.

Comment: I haven't run your code yet, but it looks like you're greatly overcomplicating things. Why doesn't `sf::st_length` work for what you want to do? It seems like that should handle having to do any type of sampling of points along the boundary

Comment: Hmm I found this and if i understand correctly it is not possible using st_length with polygon: st_length returns the length of a LINESTRING or MULTILINESTRING geometry, using the coordinate reference system. POINT, MULTIPOINT, POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON geometries return zero.

Comment: When you first read the shapefile, you've got a multipolygon object. `st_length(poly)` gets a vector of lengths in meters. So does `st_length(poly)` after you cast it as a polygon object. I'm using `sf` v0.9-6, but I don't see why that wouldn't be the case with other versions as well. Is there some other problem you're trying to solve that I'm missing?

Comment: Hi! I think you may want to check this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132422/postgis-get-the-max-length-of-the-polygon-and-the-average-width I'm not sure how to apply POSTGIS code to an sf object but we could work on it if that's what you are looking for

Comment: Do you want to calculate polygon **objects** , which are a `class` in this package, or just calculate the perimeter of an arbitrary polygon?   The latter is pretty easy if you simply calculate the Euclidean distances from one vertex to the next and sum them up

Comment: @camille st_length calculate polygon perimeter in which I am not interested. I edited my question  and added picture.

Comment: Okay, referring to the length of a polygon in that way was really unclear. I'd think of that as closer to diameter, although I don't know that that's the proper term either. What you've done as far as I understand is calculate diameters across pairs of points *randomly sampled* along the perimeters, but the question you linked uses *nodes*. Which of those do you actually want?

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar problem and frankly have not found any ready-made solution.

I will use the same Ashe county from `sf` package.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(CNTY_ID == 1825) %>% # Keep only one polygon
  st_transform(32617) # Reproject to WGS 84 / UTM zone 17N
```

##### Solution 1

What you can do with just `dplyr`, `tidyr`, and `sf` is to turn polygons into points and calculate the distance between all the points. From this variety, choose the maximal value. It would be a green line from your example figure.

```
library(tidyr)

shape %>% 
  st_cast("POINT") %>% # turn polygon into points
  distinct() %>% # remove duplicates
  st_distance() %>% # calculate distance matrix
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  gather(point_id, dist) %>% # convert to long format
  pull(dist) %>% # keep only distance column
  max()
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(., "POINT"): repeating attributes for all sub-geometries
#> for which they may not be constant
#> 45865.15 [m]
```

##### Solution 2

You can also use the [`Momocs`](https://github.com/MomX/Momocs) package. It was created for 2D morphometric analysis. While it wasn't essential to reproject our shape to UTM in the first case (`sf` can handle geographic coordinates), your polygon should be projected in the case of the `Momocs` package.

```
library(Momocs)

shape %>% 
  st_cast("POINT") %>% # Polygon to points
  distinct() %>% # remove duplicates
  st_coordinates() %>% # get coordinates matrix
  coo_calliper() # calculate max length
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(., "POINT"): repeating attributes for all sub-geometries
#> for which they may not be constant
#> [1] 45865.15
```

###### Comments

There are several other functions in the `Momocs` package. For example, you can calculate the length of a shape based on their iniertia axis i.e. alignment to the x-axis. The `coo_length` will return you `44432.02 [m]`.

For example, one can apply several functions from the `Momocs` package to the coordinate matrix as following:

```
point_matrix <- shape %>% 
  st_cast("POINT") %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  st_coordinates() 
#> Warning in st_cast.sf(., "POINT"): repeating attributes for all sub-geometries
#> for which they may not be constant

funs <- list("length" = coo_length,
             "width" = coo_width,
             "elongation" = coo_elongation)

sapply(funs, function(fun, x) fun(x), x = point_matrix)
#>       length        width   elongation 
#> 4.443202e+04 3.921162e+04 1.174917e-01
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are after circumference of your polygons consider this code:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) # included with sf package

lengths <- shape %>% 
  mutate(circumference = st_length(.)) %>% 
  st_drop_geometry() %>% 
  select(NAME, circumference) 
   
head(lengths)   
         NAME circumference
1        Ashe  141665.4 [m]
2   Alleghany  119929.0 [m]
3       Surry  160497.7 [m]
4   Currituck  301515.3 [m]
5 Northampton  211953.8 [m]
6    Hertford  160892.0 [m]
```

If you have some holes inside and do not want them included in the circumference consider removing them via `nngeo::st_remove_holes()`.

Comment: For what it's worth, `sfheaders::sf_remove_holes()` is likely faster if you have a lot of polygons and speed is a concern

Comment: Hi, I am edited the question and add picture. I am not interesting of calculating perimeter of polygon but length polygon (like here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132422/postgis-get-the-max-length-of-the-polygon-and-the-average-width )